# Disable App Update Notifications on OSX?

Tags: macos, notifications

When I have apps that need updating in OSX I get a notification on the top-right corner of my screen that does not go away until I click it (which opens the app-store). Is there a way to turn these notifications off?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

If the App store *doesn't know* about updates it should not be able to notify you - so within System Preferences go into the "App Store" preference pane and deactivate the option to search for updates automatically.

Comment: Way to think outside the box :)

Comment: On OSX Mountain Lion and earlier it's called ["Software Update",](http://km.support.apple.com/library/APPLE/APPLECARE_ALLGEOS/HT2490/en_US/HT2490-MtLion-SystemPref-001-en.png) in Mavericks it's ["App Store"](http://images.techhive.com/images/article/2013/10/mavericks_prefs_categories-we-dont-need-em-100065975-large.png)

Comment: I am admin on my MBA, I want to get notifications. My wife is not at admin and I'd like to disable App Store updates and notification for her login. Any way to disable notification for non-admin users?

Comment: I want it to check for updates but do not badger me about them. In iOS, I can change this in Settings -> Notifications -> App Store, but in OS X there is not an item for App Store in System Preferences -> Notifications.

Comment: @fossilet Unfortunately, this is currently not possible. You either have to stop OS X from searching for updates or disable notifications all-together.

Comment: Doe ssomeone know how to do this in the terminal? Would be useful to add it to a setup script.

Comment: @Asmus Unfortunately, I don't see an App Store preference pane in System Preferences. I am using macOS Big Sur.

Answer (score 6):

*In OSX Mavericks*:

You can temporarily disable the notifications by scrolling down in your notifications panel and switching the "Do Not Disturb" to On.  My understanding is that the duration of time that this is in effect is determined by your settings in System Preferences > Notifications > Do Not Disturb > From XXX to XXX.

This is explained in more detail [here](http://osxdaily.com/2013/11/12/schedule-do-not-disturb-mac-os-x/) and [here](http://reviews.cnet.com/8301-13727_7-57608829-263/how-to-turn-off-notification-center-in-os-x-mavericks/).

The [permanent solution has already been answered in this question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/106149/how-do-i-permanently-disable-notification-center-in-mavericks).

Comment: As I understand, Do Not Disturb disables all notifications –– not just notifications from the App Store.

Answer (score 0):

OSX Monterey allows creating custom "Focus" settings in Notifications & Focus.

By creating a custom Focus using a Time Schedule, and specifying specifically which apps are allowed to send you notifications you can effectively turn off all notifications.

In my experience so far this includes OS & App Store related notifications.

This is particularly useful given that the new OSX includes random add like Notifications for Safari.