# How can I disable App Store update notification for non-admin users?

Tags: macos, mac-appstore, notifications

I am admin on my MBA (Mavericks), and I want to get App Store update notifications. The rest of my family have non-admin (standard) accounts and I'd like to disable App Store updates and notification for their logins.  The answers to [Disable App Update Notifications on OSX?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/110382/disable-app-update-notifications-on-osx) apply to all users, not selective users.

Comment: This 2012 [Apple Support Community post](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/4633133) suggests disabling automatic updates in System Preferences and scheduling a scripted check as a launch agent.  I don't want to write it up as a full-fledged answer without verifying it first, but it may be worth looking into.

Answer (score 1):

There's no way to do this without sticking some funky commands in the command line. Best option is to just disable the update notifications system-wide (such as suggested in your article/link) and have the admin users check for updates manually.

Comment: I agree that's not feasible, but "some funky commands in the command line" - that's kind of implying that *there is a solution*, isn't it? ;-)