# "Updates are ready to install" but I couldn't install

Tags: mac, macos, apple-id, software-update, notifications

My company had given me an iMac to use and apps like iMovie, iPhoto had been installed by a former employee who had been using this iMac before me. Now the problem is; Updates are available for those apps, but I could not install updates of those apps because OS asks for password of that person's Apple ID. OS daily prompts me about updates but i can't install updates as well as stop notifications to prompt.

I seriously don't like these notifications and can't find a way to stop them.

I need either of the following possible solutions:

- No more "update" notifications.
- Change Apple ID of those apps.

Is there a way to achieve any??

BTW I m using OS X Mavericks 10.9.1

Answer (score 2):

See this [answers](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/110382/disable-app-update-notifications-on-osx) to your questions:

Also to take full ownership of the computer:

Make a user account with administrative privileges, and disable the other account (the previous owner)

Comment: I don't think that changing the settings in the iTunes store (your second option) will change the behaviour of the Mac App Store.