# Disable "Updates Ready to Install"

Tags: macos, auto-update

Apps from OS X 10.9 (Mavericks) have started to ask me to restart when there are updates ready to install. Is it possible to completely disable this notification?

Screenshot of notification:

[image: updates-ready-to-install]

Comment: see this answer http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/110382/disable-app-update-notifications-on-osx

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To stop the notifications, go to System Preferences > App Store and disable 'check automatically for updates.' This will stop the notifications. This was from http://lifehacker.com/how-to-fix-os-x-mavericks-biggest-annoyances-1450220339

Comment: FYI, I voted to close this question as duplicate, sorry.

Comment: If you want to be specific answer the "Updates are ready to Install"- Restart-Later question.