# How do I re-enable Notification Center in Yosemite or El Capitan post-upgrade?

Tags: macos

I believe I followed the advice here: [How do I permanently disable Notification Center in Mavericks?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/106149/how-do-i-permanently-disable-notification-center-in-mavericks)

Post upgrade to Yosemite, the Notification Center icon shows up in the menu bar, but clicking on it does nothing, as noted by this individual: https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/142921/96853

Comment: Apple has a tendency to move (or rename) files in new OS version.Try locating the file using Terminal "mdfind com.apple.notificationcenterui.plist" to see where it is on 10.10

Answer (score 24, accepted):

This in Terminal will show Notification Center again:

```
launchctl load -w /System/Library/LaunchAgents/com.apple.notificationcenterui.plist
killall NotificationCenter
```

You will have to restart your Mac afterwards.

Reported to work in El Capitan (10.11.1) as well.

Comment: While we love your educated guesses, it is recommended to Try it your self and confirm or provide reference where that worked. This is to avoid people trying terminal commands with questionable outcome (protection). Note I did not vote down giving you a chance to respond.

Comment: Alright, will temp delete and try it.

Comment: Verified & edited.

Comment: Unfortunately, this did not work for me. How did you test this exactly? My scenario is I disabled notifications pre-Yosemite and then upgraded, so it's not the same as just disabling/enabling on Yosemite.

Comment: Ok, what was the error message in terminal? Might want to edit your question for this. Also, @Buscar웃, should I delete this answer, considering it isn't correct?

Comment: @mehmenmike You said you tested it on your Mac? if you did not have the proper OS to do that then consider revising or deleting.

Comment: @Buscar웃 I did, on Yosemite. Read Bowen's last comment.

Comment: Bugger. I missed the part about restarting the computer. Works now! Thanks!

Comment: i had a problem with gulp-notify because i disable this feature