# Notification center does not open

Tags: macos, notifications

Ever since upgrading to Yosemite 2 days ago my notifications no longer work. I can't even open the notification center by clicking the icon in the menubar. Nothing happens when i click it.

Anyone know what's going on or where to look to further investigate the issue?

Comment: Perhaps this command : launchctl load -w /System/Library/LaunchAgents/com.apple.notificationcenterui.plist

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same problem and found an answer on this site. Did you ever use Terminal to disable Notification Center in and earlier OS? I did, and this tip brought it back - [How do I re-enable Notification Center in Yosemite or El Capitan post-upgrade?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/152064/how-do-i-re-enable-notification-center-in-yosemite-post-upgrade)

Comment: Thanks to http://apple.stackexchange.com/users/95661/mehmenmike for the original discovery.